# Multidimensional array as a flat array problem

Tags: c++, brew-framework

I'm looking at two lines of code that somebody wrote and there is an exception in the 2nd one, however I don't understand why.

```
char** array = (char**) new char [2] [6];

std_strlprintf(array[0],6,"[%d]", num);
```

std_strlprintf is a Brew function that writes formatted output to a string. (num is an integral value which is 0)

Why is there an exception with this code, what's wrong with accessing the first elelment of the array as buff[0]?

---

EDIT: sorry there was a typo in my initial posting. Its corrected now.
THis is the code that has the exception.

Comment: one the first line your declaring a variable with name 'array'... what's buff? do you mean std_strlprintf(array[0],6,"[%d]", num); - but then should it be std_strlprintf(array[0][0],6,"[%d]", num);

Comment: If you need to cast when you new you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Ues I did mean that, but if it was array[0][0] then that would be passing a char not a char* to std_strlprintf().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two-dimensional array is not the same as *array of pointers*.

Your first statement creates two arrays of six chars each *as a single memory block*. Replace that statement with:

```
char (*array)[6] = new char [2][6];
```

and you'll be all set with your second statement. Don't forget to

```
delete [] array;
```

#### Edit 0:

Huh, I should've known :) To your question in the comment:

> How should I subsequently pass array
>   to a function that takes a `char**` as a
>   parameter?

You don't. Not in this form. If you are building a list of parameters to some C API like [`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), you have to go all the way with two-stage initialization:

```
// prototype of the function to call
void my_fancy_func( int argc, char* const argv[] );

char** my_argv = new char*[my_argc];

for ( i = 0; i < my_argc; i++ ) {
    my_argv[i] = new char[arg_buffer_size];
    snprintf( my_argv[i], arg_buffer_size, "%d", i );
}

my_fancy_func( my_argc, my_argv );
```

Comment: Thanks, how should I subsequently pass array to a function that takes a char** as a parameter?